# Cannot read property 'southwest' of undefined in Cesium

Tags: typescript, cesiumjs

```
update(value:number) {
    this.altitude=value;
    this._viewer.camera.flyTo({
        destination : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(this._viewer.Longitude,this._viewer.Latitude, value)
    });
```

I want to make it so that the function changes the height of the map, but there it must also take the coordinates of the point, and I need to change the height at any point where I am

Comment: without using const points

Comment: Can you explain this question a little better?  It's hard to follow what you're asking here.

Comment: You need to explain where you are getting the error in your title.  I don’t see “southwest” referenced anywhere here.  Based on the title alone, my guess is that you have an object that might or might not be defined and you have to verify that it’s not undefined before using it.

Comment: @LindaPaiste I have a map in cesium and I need to write a function that will change the height of the camera that the user has entered, my function does not work correctly because I still need to enter the longitude and latitude, but I don’t know what to enter, or tell me the function that accepts the camera height parameter, without longitude and latitude

Comment: @emackey explained